# Remove Spacing above Heading with removed Chapter-Text

Tags: spacing, chapters, titlesec

I've a problem with removing the space above the Chapter text, when I've removed the "chapter". My minimal example is down below. In the image I show which space I'd like to reduce. I tried a lot with the `\usepackage{titlesec}` but it doesn't work in my case.
Can I change something in the redefinition?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Remove "Chapter"-Text
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
  \makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Change `\vspace*{50\p@}%` to `\vspace*{0\p@}%` or remove that line. Why don't you use `\chapter*{...}` instead?

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly
I've got a table of content (TOC) and with `\chapter*{...}`this chapter is missing in the TOC.
Is there a way that also to decrease the spacing between the title of the TOC and the border?

Comment: You have to do the same for `\@makeschapterhead`. I will put down an answer a bit later. I am held up for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the line `\vspace*{50\p@}%` to get rid of the space above the title. To get the same effect, do the same for  `\@makeschapterhead` (note `s` in schapterhead).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}  %% remove showframe


% Remove "Chapter"-Text
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%    %% <------ remove this line
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%    %% <------ remove this line
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `titlesec`, you may try some thing like:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{}   %{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
{0pt} %{20pt}
{\Huge}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{40pt}   % default {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{-40pt}{40pt}
```